# How can i Refresh a specific Div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the JQuery UI draggble, and i'm sending automatically to my database table informations from the transitions that are made. When some item is dropped into a certain div, i call a PHP function to record this information into a specific table.

I did that using Ajax:

```
$(".event").draggable({ helper: "clone"  });
$(".drop").droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
         var targetid = event.target.id ;

        $.ajax( {
            type: 'get',
            url: "modules/groups/new.php",
             data : { 'target_id' : targetid, 'drag_id' : id},
             success: function( response ) {

            }
        });

    }
});
```

Since i'm using Ajax, everytime that this PHP function is called, it doesn't refresh the page, so i would like to refresh automatically the divs that were dropped.

I tried to do that:

The target id is the id from the dropabble div:

```
$div = '<div id="'.$list_day.'" class="drop" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)";>';
```

So, i tried to refresh this specific div everytime that a transition is made:

```
        $(".event").draggable({ helper: "clone"  });
        $(".drop").droppable({

            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                 var targetid = event.target.id ;

                $.ajax( {
                    type: 'get',
                    url: "modules/groups/new.php",
                     data : { 'target_id' : targetid, 'drag_id' : id},
                     success: function( response ) {


    $(targetid).load(window.location.href + targetid);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

But i had no success doing that... What do i need to do?

Comment: Care to explain what you're trying to do with `$(targetid).load(window.location.href + targetid);`? I don't think it does what you *think* it does. Why aren't you using the response data from `$.ajax` for *anything*?

Comment: I was trying to refresh only the dropabble div

Comment: I understand that, but are you aware of what `window.location.href + targetid` evaluates to?

Comment: may be it's this you are looking for `$("#" + targetid).html(response);`

Comment: Everytime that i do the transitions, the page doesn't refresh, to show everything that was changed, i have to refresh the page using F5, so, i want to refresh the draggble div where the element was dropabble, to show the updates refreshing automatically

Comment: What you want is not to "refresh" the div but instead try to rebuild it with the data you got from the ajax response i think @Khalid has the answer you are looking for to do that.